# On button click change a value outside a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change or make the app variable in the config parameter dynamic. For that I created some radio buttons with value. So wondering how can I pass the value based on user preference.
2) Second, if the selection is changed from selection1 to selection2, then it should auto refresh.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../resources/assets/client/client.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="sense-search.min.css"/>
    </head>
    <input type="radio" name = "Product" value = "987-34587a8a5e13" /> abc
    <input type="radio" name = "Product" value = "786-2fad2cbd8249" /> def
    <body style="width: 100%; margin: 20px auto; font-family: arial;">


        <h2></h2>
        <br>
        <sense-search-input id="myInput" mode="visualizations"></sense-search-input>
        <sense-search-results id="myResults"></sense-search-results>
        <script type="text/javascript" 
src="../../resources/assets/external/requirejs/require.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="sense-search.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">


            //var str ;

            //$("input[name=Product]").click(function(){
                //alert("selected");
            //});

            var config = {
                host: "xyz",
                prefix: "/pnb/",
                isSecure: true,
                app: '987-34587a8a5e13',
                port: 443
            }
```

Comment: What do you mean by __pass the value based on user preference__? Do you want it in a post-request?

Comment: *"it should auto refresh"* ... What is **"it"**? Please take some time to read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: @Arun Chandra Kathula: display elements (e.g. inputs) should be placed under the body element.

Comment: You didn't wrote any Js/jQuery code? programming is not free, in here we try to solve problems not write code from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Free code.
https://api.jquery.com/change/

Just listen to change event of that input... when it changes...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type=radio][name=Product]').change(function() {
         app.yourstuff = this.value;
         alert("selected "+this.value);
    });
});
```

Comment: or use the vanilla js `onchange`